# Supervisor gets a SIGTERM for some reason, quits and stops all its processes

Tags: ubuntu, supervisord

I use supervisor on an Ubuntu 12.04 machine (installed with `pip`) to run gunicorn and Django.

I start `supervisord` and everything is fine. I can reach my Django app through the nginx server which proxies gunicorn. The problem is, that after a few hours or even a day, supervisor stops. The supervisor log shows `WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request` and the lines following are the shutting down of the 'supervised' processes.

I'm not really sure what is going on and what sends the SIGTERM. I searched Google and found someone who had a similar problem and opened an issue in GitHub, but he closed it, and his solution was not related to my setup: https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/321

I read a bit further about an our-of-memory issue sending a SIGTERM, but my server does not run high on resources and has plenty of free memory.

What can I do to debug this issue better?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: I'm not using that machine anymore, but as far as I recall I made a cronjob that checks if the supervisor pid exists, and if not, logs a message to a file and restart supervisor. It kind of misses the whole point of supervisor this way, doesn't it? The interesting thing is that the 'supervisor_death.log' file did not seem to have any new entries at some point.

How would you describe the problem you are facing?

Comment: "The supervisor log shows WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request and the lines following are the shutting down of the 'supervised' processes." - I have same problem today

Comment: Me too. 50% of my infrastructure on AWS received that. Can't explain.

Comment: Same here. 20% of machines in 15 different data-centers had the same issue around 6:30am UTC.

Comment: Check `/var/log/apt/history.log` (ubuntu). I found out there was unattended-upgrade of supervisor. So that's it! The same time.

Comment: @vvucetic good catch!

Comment: these are the kinds of issues avoided by executing prod code inside a container ( docker ) into which you install say supervisor and your application code which gets deployed meaning its read only inside the container which by default  `unattended-upgrade` package is not needed nor installed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comment under the question is definitely a good answer:

> Check /var/log/apt/history.log (ubuntu). I found out there was unattended-upgrade of supervisor.

In my case, I checked the timestamps of the `SIGTERM` in `/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log` and `Start-Date` in `/var/log/apt/history.log`.  They were indeed the same time, which all but confirms the fact that auto updates were the problem here.

To turn those off, like in [this tutorial](https://www.garron.me/en/linux/turn-off-stop-ubuntu-automatic-update.html), you can modify `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` to have the value:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
```

Comment: It's been a long time and I'm not using a supervisor solution at the moment in any of my apps, but I do believe this is the correct answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a health check running in docker-compose that was failing, which was the cause of the docker container receiving SIGTERM and restarting.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I received this error via `service`.
The file I wrote:

```
[Unit]
Description=Supervisor Process

[Service]
User=zscaler
Group=zscaler
ExecStart=supervisord -c /personal/supervisord.conf
StandardOutput=file:/personal/logs/supervisord_stdout.log
StandardError=file:/personal/logs/supervisord_stderr.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run the `ExecStart` command manually - it worked, when I tried `service supervisord start` it gave the error you received (`received SIGTERM indicating exit request`)

The only thing i could think of, was that manually it auto convert to deamon. and then I thought that maybe the service expect something else.

I added `-n` (`-n|nodeamon` to the `ExecStart=supervisord -n -c ...` and the error disappeared...